# MVC + Jquery - return to the page with ajax uploaded content after redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've encountered the following problem:

I have a page with some content which I uploaded using jQuery ajax. Then I click on a link and get a redirect to another page. Is it possible to return to the first page with ajax content (without another upload)?

I use mvc5 + jQuery for the project.

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: this is my repo https://github.com/morow93/inoreader but i thought that i can just call one jquery method and get the page with all content (also with ajax uploaded content)

Comment: i have a page with categories (entities) and each category has a links (entities also). i did a paging with ajax and when i'll click on the link i need to open new page with form for edit this entity(link). afte edit i need return to the page with categories (each category has a links, don't forget) and select right page - right category page and right link page.